# Invalid hook call using material UI

Tags: reactjs, json, material-ui, dependencies

I don't have useStyles like many other questions do. All I did to get the error was including an empty Grid in body like so:

```
import Grid from '@mui/material/Grid'; 

export const index = () => {
  return (
    <>
       <body>
          <Grid container spacing={1}>
          </Grid>
       </body>
    </>
  )
}
```

I tried removing "react" and "react-dom" from package.json but it didn't work. Some solutions suggested manipulating the webpack file but I don't see it. Here's my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "name",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "lint:fix": "next lint --fix",
    "format": "prettier . --write"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.4.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.3.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^5.0.0-beta.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "next": "11.0.1",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-audio-player": "^0.17.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.6.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "17.0.15",
    "eslint": "7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "11.0.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-simple-import-sort": "^7.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "prettier": "^2.3.2",
    "typescript": "4.3.5",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "webpack": "^5.45.1"
  }
}
```

Here's the error

```
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
    at resolveDispatcher (/Users/alisonqiu/node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:1476:13)
    at Object.useContext (/Users/alisonqiu/node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:1484:20)
    at useTheme (/Users/alisonqiu/node_modules/@mui/private-theming/node/useTheme/useTheme.js:19:23)
    at useTheme (/Users/alisonqiu/node_modules/@mui/system/useThemeWithoutDefault.js:15:53)
    at useTheme (/Users/alisonqiu/node_modules/@mui/system/useTheme.js:18:46)
    at useThemeProps (/Users/alisonqiu/node_modules/@mui/system/useThemeProps/useThemeProps.js:19:39)
    at useThemeProps (/Users/alisonqiu/node_modules/@mui/material/node/styles/useThemeProps.js:18:36)
    at Object.Grid [as render] (/Users/alisonqiu/node_modules/@mui/material/node/Grid/Grid.js:317:49)
    at ReactDOMServerRenderer.render (/Users/alisonqiu/Downloads/orcahome1/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:3872:44)
    at ReactDOMServerRenderer.read (/Users/alisonqiu/Downloads/orcahome1/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:3690:29)
wait  - compiling...
event - compiled successfully
wait  - compiling...
HookWebpackError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'replace')
    at makeWebpackError (/Users/alisonqiu/Downloads/orcahome1/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:58378:9)
    at /Users/alisonqiu/Downloads/orcahome1/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:43243:12
    at eval (eval at create (/Users/alisonqiu/Downloads/orcahome1/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:31934:10), <anonymous>:12:1)
    at fn (/Users/alisonqiu/Downloads/orcahome1/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:41175:17)
    at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/Users/alisonqiu/Downloads/orcahome1/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:31934:10), <anonymous>:10:1)
    at Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync] (/Users/alisonqiu/Downloads/orcahome1/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:31736:14)
    at cont (/Users/alisonqiu/Downloads/orcahome1/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:43240:34)
    at /Users/alisonqiu/Downloads/orcahome1/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:43286:10
    at /Users/alisonqiu/Downloads/orcahome1/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/neo-async/async.js:1:9438
    at Object.each (/Users/alisonqiu/Downloads/orcahome1/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/neo-async/async.js:1:9616)
-- inner error --
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'replace')
    at PagesManifestPlugin.createAssets (/Users/alisonqiu/Downloads/orcahome1/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/plugins/pages-manifest-plugin.js:5:148)
    at /Users/alisonqiu/Downloads/orcahome1/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/plugins/pages-manifest-plugin.js:7:82
    at fn (/Users/alisonqiu/Downloads/orcahome1/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:41173:10)
    at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/Users/alisonqiu/Downloads/orcahome1/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:31934:10), <anonymous>:10:1)
    at Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync] (/Users/alisonqiu/Downloads/orcahome1/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:31736:14)
    at cont (/Users/alisonqiu/Downloads/orcahome1/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:43240:34)
    at /Users/alisonqiu/Downloads/orcahome1/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:43286:10
    at /Users/alisonqiu/Downloads/orcahome1/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/neo-async/async.js:1:9438
    at Object.each (/Users/alisonqiu/Downloads/orcahome1/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/neo-async/async.js:1:9616)
    at Compilation.createChunkAssets (/Users/alisonqiu/Downloads/orcahome1/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:44517:12)
caused by plugins in Compilation.hooks.processAssets
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'replace')
    at PagesManifestPlugin.createAssets (/Users/alisonqiu/Downloads/orcahome1/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/plugins/pages-manifest-plugin.js:5:148)
    at /Users/alisonqiu/Downloads/orcahome1/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/plugins/pages-manifest-plugin.js:7:82
    at fn (/Users/alisonqiu/Downloads/orcahome1/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:41173:10)
    at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/Users/alisonqiu/Downloads/orcahome1/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:31934:10), <anonymous>:10:1)
    at Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync] (/Users/alisonqiu/Downloads/orcahome1/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:31736:14)
    at cont (/Users/alisonqiu/Downloads/orcahome1/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:43240:34)
    at /Users/alisonqiu/Downloads/orcahome1/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:43286:10
    at /Users/alisonqiu/Downloads/orcahome1/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/neo-async/async.js:1:9438
    at Object.each (/Users/alisonqiu/Downloads/orcahome1/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/neo-async/async.js:1:9616)
    at Compilation.createChunkAssets (/Users/alisonqiu/Downloads/orcahome1/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:44517:12)
HookWebpackError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'replace')
    at makeWebpackError (/Users/alisonqiu/Downloads/orcahome1/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:58378:9)
    at /Users/alisonqiu/Downloads/orcahome1/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:43243:12
    at eval (eval at create (/Users/alisonqiu/Downloads/orcahome1/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:31934:10), <anonymous>:12:1)
    at fn (/Users/alisonqiu/Downloads/orcahome1/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:41175:17)
    at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/Users/alisonqiu/Downloads/orcahome1/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:31934:10), <anonymous>:10:1)
    at Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync] (/Users/alisonqiu/Downloads/orcahome1/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:31736:14)
    at cont (/Users/alisonqiu/Downloads/orcahome1/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:43240:34)
    at /Users/alisonqiu/Downloads/orcahome1/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:43286:10
    at /Users/alisonqiu/Downloads/orcahome1/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/neo-async/async.js:1:9438
    at Object.each (/Users/alisonqiu/Downloads/orcahome1/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/neo-async/async.js:1:9616)
-- inner error --
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'replace')
    at PagesManifestPlugin.createAssets (/Users/alisonqiu/Downloads/orcahome1/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/plugins/pages-manifest-plugin.js:5:148)
    at /Users/alisonqiu/Downloads/orcahome1/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/plugins/pages-manifest-plugin.js:7:82
    at fn (/Users/alisonqiu/Downloads/orcahome1/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:41173:10)
    at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/Users/alisonqiu/Downloads/orcahome1/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:31934:10), <anonymous>:10:1)
    at Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync] (/Users/alisonqiu/Downloads/orcahome1/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:31736:14)
    at cont (/Users/alisonqiu/Downloads/orcahome1/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:43240:34)
    at /Users/alisonqiu/Downloads/orcahome1/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:43286:10
    at /Users/alisonqiu/Downloads/orcahome1/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/neo-async/async.js:1:9438
    at Object.each (/Users/alisonqiu/Downloads/orcahome1/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/neo-async/async.js:1:9616)
    at Compilation.createChunkAssets (/Users/alisonqiu/Downloads/orcahome1/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:44517:12)
caused by plugins in Compilation.hooks.processAssets
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'replace')
    at PagesManifestPlugin.createAssets (/Users/alisonqiu/Downloads/orcahome1/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/plugins/pages-manifest-plugin.js:5:148)
    at /Users/alisonqiu/Downloads/orcahome1/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/plugins/pages-manifest-plugin.js:7:82
    at fn (/Users/alisonqiu/Downloads/orcahome1/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:41173:10)
    at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/Users/alisonqiu/Downloads/orcahome1/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:31934:10), <anonymous>:10:1)
    at Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync] (/Users/alisonqiu/Downloads/orcahome1/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:31736:14)
    at cont (/Users/alisonqiu/Downloads/orcahome1/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:43240:34)
    at /Users/alisonqiu/Downloads/orcahome1/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:43286:10
    at /Users/alisonqiu/Downloads/orcahome1/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/neo-async/async.js:1:9438
    at Object.each (/Users/alisonqiu/Downloads/orcahome1/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/neo-async/async.js:1:9616)
    at Compilation.createChunkAssets (/Users/alisonqiu/Downloads/orcahome1/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:44517:12)
```

Comment: Your first body tag is `</body>` instead of `<body>`. But also, do you need the body tag? Normally a react app is rendered in a root div inside the body of index.html

Comment: Is there a reason you're using a beta version of MUI? Also, are you sure this is the source of your problem? I think you're looking in the wrong place for you problem/solution. How are you using `index`? React components should begin with an uppercase first letter as well..

Comment: Your package.json says `"@material-ui/core": "^5.0.0-beta.0"`, but you're importing as `@mui`? Which do you actually have installed?

Comment: @ChiefMcFrank sorry when I created this question I didn't copy it correctly, but the body tag is not the issue

Comment: @BrianThompson This repo is built using nextJS. maybe that's why index is lowercase. The program was working fine until I tried to swap MUI out for bootstrap

Comment: @BrianThompson 

I have 

├─┬ @mui/icons-material@5.2.5
│ └── @mui/material@5.3.1 deduped
└── @mui/material@5.3.1
Could the problem be related to that line in my json file?

Comment: No, the package.json does not reflect what's actually installed, and that's what matters here. I would highly suggest that you correct the package.json, but it won't fix this. NextJS does not change the rules of react components.

Comment: *working fine until I tried to swap MUI out for bootstrap* - are you having the error with MUI or bootstrap? I don't see bootstrap mentioned anywhere in the question?

Comment: If mui/material@5.3.1 is what's actually installed, how can I fix the react hook problem? The program was originally built using bootstrap and everything worked fine. We want to move it to using MUI now

Answer (score -2):

it has something to do with the differences in the nature of the concepts of binding declarations and default exports, So you're trying to export and declare a variable at the same time!

So your code could be

```
import Grid from '@mui/material/Grid'; 

export default () => {
  return (
    <>
       <body>
          <Grid container spacing={1}>
          </Grid>
       </body>
    </>
  )
}
```

or

```
import Grid from '@mui/material/Grid'; 

const Index = () => {
  return (
    <>
       <body>
          <Grid container spacing={1}>
          </Grid>
       </body>
    </>
  )
}

export default Index;
```

Codesandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/basicgrid-material-demo-forked-60787?file=/demo.js

You could read more about this topic at

https://esdiscuss.org/topic/why-is-export-default-var-a-1-invalid-syntax

Comment: Tried export default index = () => { and got the following error: ReferenceError: index is not defined. 

Tried the second option and still got invalid hook call

Comment: @AlisonQiu I've updated my answer and I've provided a working Codesandbox for you.

Comment: Could you let me know what you changed from your original suggestion (code-wise)  besides adding Codesandbox?

Comment: @AlisonQiu I just removed the " Index =  "